# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #gatePermissions[] when I click on a checkbox or select dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click the Checkbox or select the dropdown menu I get the error.
If I change the name="gatePermissions[]" to name="gatePermissions" there is no error.

I have no jQuery validation on these items at all, seems as if jQuery doesn't like the checkbox array, but I need gatePermissions in the form as an array.

I am using jQuery on this form for a calendar date picker, but that has no effect when I select or manipulate the date picker. Only the Dropdown menus and the checkboxes.

Tried updating jQuery to 3.5.1 but this has no effect.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gatePermissions[]" value="1"> One<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gatePermissions[]" value="2"> Two<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gatePermissions[]" value="3"> Three<br />


<select name="selectOption" required="required" class="">
    <option value="">---Please Select---</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>

jquery.min.js:formatted:539 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #gatePermissions[]
at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:formatted:539)
at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:formatted:867)
at fa.select (jquery.min.js:formatted:1037)
at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:formatted:308)
at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:formatted:1156)
at new n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:formatted:1179)
at n (jquery.min.js:formatted:22)
at form-parser.js:28
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at createFormObj (form-parser.js:25)

<script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('#arrivalDate .input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        startDate: '-0d',
        todayBtn: 'linked',
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
      }).on('changeDate',function(e){
          //on change of date on start datepicker, set end datepicker's date
          $('#departureDate .input-group.date').datepicker('setStartDate',e.date)
      });

       $('#departureDate .input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        startDate: '-0d',
        todayBtn: 'linked',
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
       }).on('changeDate',function(e){
           //on change of date on start datepicker, set end datepicker's date
           $('#arrivalDate .input-group.date').datepicker('setEndDate',e.date)
       });
       $('#dayPassDate .input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        startDate: '-0d',
        todayBtn: 'linked',
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
       });
       $("#longTerm").click(function(){
          var longTerm = '2050-07-15';
          $('input[name="ValidTo"]').val(longTerm);
      });
      });
    </script>
```

In the Console the error points to: form-parser.js and the below code snippet: basically the forEach function

```
// Creates a mapping of element names to their values and classes within a form
var createFormObj = function (data) {
var formObj = {};
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function (id) {
var attMap = {};
var name = data[id]['name'];
attMap['class'] = $('#' + name).attr('class');
attMap['value'] = data[id]['value'];
formObj[data[id]['name']] = attMap;
  });
  removeUserInfo(formObj);
  return formObj;
};
```

Comment: Where does "php" come into play? Yet alone the other tags used. This should have just been "HTML" because that's all there is here (so far).

Comment: Not my downvote you got but I'd start by looking at the developer console. I'm no JS/jQuery guru, but that's usually the first place to look in.

Comment: Downvote with no comment is not helpful at all! See JQuery Error message

Comment: Google the error "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #" and you might find your answer. I found many but I won't be of much help here, sorry. I'm mostly a serverside coder.

Comment: I have Googled all over nothing helpful at all.

Comment: Where is your jquery code?

Comment: Added the jQuery which is only related to the datePicker

Comment: we need to see where you catch gatePermissions in jquery

Comment: As I mentioned I don't use jQuery to catch gatePermissions at all. It's just an array being processed through PHP validation.

Comment: Php return with ajax and use it to jquery?

Comment: I'm using a pure JavaScript fetch Promise function to validate a blur event on a text input field in this form but there's no jQuery associated with that at all. If I comment out the JavaScript function it has no effect at all, stil get the jQuery error!

Comment: i can't understand how jquery randomly catch #gatePermissions[]

Comment: Weird hey, no idea myself, I've used checkbox arrays many time before, no issues

Comment: In the Console the error points to: form-parser.js and it's forEach function - I updated my question with  the code

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I had the Chrome extension Form Vault installed. This was causing the issue. I uninstalled it and there is no longer an issue.